# Не работают прокси при запросе к Gemini

Tags: прокси

Подключаюсь к прокси через этот метод:
Вот эта штука стоит в начале кода, перед запросами к OpenAI и Gemini

```
proxy_ip = 
proxy_port = 
proxy_username = 
proxy_password = 
socks.set_default_proxy(socks.SOCKS5, proxy_ip, proxy_port, username=proxy_username, password=proxy_password)
socket.socket = socks.socksocket
```

При запросе к openai всё шик, запрос через прокси

```
# Функция для отправки запроса в модель GPT-3.5 Turbo с использованием кэширования
def get_openai_response(message):
    user_id = message.from_user.id
    client = OpenAI(api_key=get_next_openai_token())
    processing_message = bot.reply_to(message, f"{loading}Обработка запроса...")
    global openai_context
    openai_context[user_id] = []
    
    # Создаем тело запроса
    user_message = {"role": "user", "content": message.text}
    assistant_messages = [{"role": message[1]["role"], "content": message[1]["text"]} for message in openai_context[user_id] if message[1]["role"] in ["user", "assistant"]]
    assistant_messages.append(user_message)

    response = client.chat.completions.create(
        model=MODELS_GPT,
        messages=assistant_messages,
        max_tokens=4000
    )
    if response:
      assistant_response = response.choices[0].message.content

    # Обновляем кэш OpenAI, добавляя текущий запрос
      current_time = time.time()
    # Удаляем старые записи из контекста
      openai_context[user_id] = [
              (timestamp, message) for timestamp, message in openai_context[user_id]
              if current_time - timestamp <= EXPIRY_TIME
      ]
      # Добавляем только последний ответ ассистента в контекст
      if message.text:
          openai_context[user_id] = [(current_time, {"role": "user", "text": message.text}), (current_time, {"role": "assistant", "text":  assistant_response})]
      else:
          openai_context[user_id] = [(current_time, {"role": "assistant", "text":  assistant_response})]
      bot.delete_message(message.chat.id, processing_message.message_id)
      # Ограничиваем размер контекста
      if len(openai_context[user_id]) > MAX_CONTEXT_SIZE:
          openai_context[user_id] = openai_context[user_id][-MAX_CONTEXT_SIZE:]
      return assistant_response
```

А при запросе к Gemini, запрос почему то с моего айпи:

```
# Функция для получения ответа с помощью Gemini
def get_gemini_response(message, images=None):
    user_id = message.from_user.id
    genai.configure(api_key='')
    global gemini_context
    gemini_context[user_id] = []
    processing_message = bot.reply_to(message, f"{loading}Обработка запроса...")
    # Выбор соответствующей модели в зависимости от наличия изображений
    model_name = 'gemini-pro-vision' if images else 'gemini-pro'
    model = genai.GenerativeModel(model_name)
    # Подготовка сообщений для многоходового чата
    user_message = {"role": "user", "parts": [message.text]}
    assistant_messages = [{"role": message[1]["role"], "parts": [message[1]["text"]]} for message in gemini_context[user_id] if message[1]["role"] in ["user", "model"]]
    assistant_messages.append(user_message)
    # Генерация контента на основе ввода
    if images:
        # Если предоставлены изображения, создайте мультимодальный запрос
        img_objects = [PIL.Image.open(f"{user_id}_chat_image.jpg")]
        if message.caption:
            multimodal_prompt = [message.caption] + img_objects
        else:
            multimodal_prompt = img_objects
        response = model.generate_content(multimodal_prompt)
    else:
        # Для текстовых запросов или чата используйте generate_content
        response = model.generate_content(assistant_messages)
    if images:
        os.remove(f"{user_id}_chat_image.jpg")
    current_time = time.time()
    # Удаляем старые записи из контекста
    gemini_context[user_id] = [
        (timestamp, message) for timestamp, message in gemini_context[user_id]
        if current_time - timestamp <= EXPIRY_TIME
    ]
    message_caption = message.text if message.text else message.caption if message.caption else None
    # Добавляем только последний ответ ассистента в контекст
    gemini_context[user_id] = [(current_time, {"role": "user", "parts": message_caption}), (current_time, {"role": "model", "parts": response.text})]
    bot.delete_message(message.chat.id, processing_message.message_id)
    # Обработка ответа и возврат текста
    return response.text
```

Подключался к прокси, через OpenAi запрос через прокси и не выдаёт ошибку, что запрещённый айпи, а на Gemini нет.